# Handlebar issue after upgrading to ember-cli 0.2.2

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, handlebars.js

I upgraded ember-cli from 0.1.7 to 0.2.2 a few hours back.... now I get an error in one of my handlebar templates in a nested '#each' block that refers to a property using double dot notation. The error is

```
Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: KeyStream error: key must be a non-empty string
```

The lines in the .hbs file that triggers this:

```
{{#each dir in ../subDirs}}
  <a class="file-link" {{action 'fileClicked' dir.name}}>{{dir.name}}</a><br/>
{{/each}}
```

The error does not appear if the above 3 lines are removed.

The line in the processed application js file that triggers the error:

```
block(env, morph1, context, "each", [get(env, context, "../subDirs")], {"keyword": "dir"}, child0, null);
```

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: This also seems to be happening when inside an each as well:

`{{#each option in options}} ... {{../otherValue}} {{/each}}`

Comment: I solved the issue by removing the '../' part from the '../subDirs'. I was of the opinion that inside a nested each block, variables declared above the parent scope will not be available and used the double dot notation specified in handlebars docs. Apparently, it IS available. I'm not sure if its the case only with HTMLBars (which is the one used in latest ember) or if thats how handlebars also work!!